# KNIME Concatenate node with List Files/Folders loop?

Tags: excel, concatenation, data-analysis, data-mining, knime

Knime. I know how to use "Concatenate" node with multiple Excel readers, so that all spreadsheets are combined together, even if their structure is different.
In case of having many such spreadsheet, manual definition of each Excel reader is painful and I would like to use "List Files/Folders" node instead. I know how to use "List Files/Folders" with "Table Row to Variable" loop and "Excel reader", but this works only if all spreadsheets have exactly the same structure. So, I cannot use Excel reader in the loop, but I should use "Concatenate" node instead.
However, I don't know how to embed Concatenate node in a loop - is it even possible?

Comment: The Loop End node has a table input and concatenates the rows of this input for each iteration of the loop into a single output table - doesn't that do what you need? If not, please show some more detail of what you're trying to do, with screenshots and/or example data.

Answer (score 0):

It works:
[workflow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ep6Ov.png)

You need to change "Loop End" settings: choose "Allow changing table specifications"